# Apple IAP "You're All Set" alert doesn't always show

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, storekit2

I haven't been able to determine a pattern for when it will show and when it won't. The purchases are all successful though. Behind the scenes, the StoreKit2 returns data showing they've made the purchase/upgrade and apple sends my dev server the transaction notifications via the AppStore Server API.

Any idea why the "You're All Set" alert isn't being shown?

```
func purchase(_ product: Product, appaccounttoken: UUID) async throws -> Transaction? {
    // Begin purchasing the `Product` the user selects.
    let result = try await product.purchase(options: [.appAccountToken(appaccounttoken)])

    switch result {
        case .success(let verification):
            // Check whether the transaction is verified. If it isn't,
            // this function rethrows the verification error.
            let transaction = try checkverified(verification)

            // The transaction is verified. Deliver content to the user.
            await updatecustomerproductstatus()

            // Always finish a transaction.
            await transaction.finish()

            return transaction


        case .userCancelled, .pending:
            return nil

        default:
            return nil
    }
}
```

which is called by ...

```
if let transaction = try await self.purchase(product, appaccounttoken: uuid) {
    return transaction.id
}
```

which is called by ...

```
if let transactionid = try await Store.store.subscribe(id: productid, owner: self.owner) {
    print("transaction: \(transactionid)")

    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)

}
```

In my testing, the "You're All Set" alert is shown and then AFTER I tap the "OK" button on it, the code returns to the `try await Store.store.subscribe()` call and then prints my transaction id and dismisses the view controller.

But sometimes, and without any pattern I can discern, the transaction completes, the transaction id is returned from my `try await Store.store.subscribe()` call and my view controller is dismissed... but the "You're All Set" alert never pops up.